# Woocommerce Custom Product Type of Simple

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add custom product type in Woocommerce admin.

A new product type should be of simple product type.

Find out the following image for more description.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6n5mN7sueSDOEF0UkhYMjFYSDA/edit

Thanks and Regards
Chirag

Comment: Here you go : [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120215/how-to-add-a-new-product-type-on-woocommerce-product-types][1]

But its quite a complicated task.


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120215/how-to-add-a-new-product-type-on-woocommerce-product-types

Comment: Hi pushpak thanks for the reply. What i want is i want product type of simple